# passing serialzed object using RMI

Tags: java, rmi

I need to invoke a method in rmi server and pass a serialized object to the method from client side but the class of the object is unknown to the server

Comment: Does your server program has the class in question in its classpath?

Comment: You have to specify the codebase, otherwise, it won't work

Comment: I can't offer the class of the passing object in the server side

Answer (score -1):

As you've already been told, the only way to accomplish that is by use of the codebase feature.